# Should we encourage voteup upon answering?

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

Should we encourage users to +1 each question, they find at least that interesting, that they're deciding to answer? AFAIK, this case isn't certain among other SE sites.

I personally find this fair and professional. We have opposite mechanism (if answer is good, its author is awarded with +1 or even acceptance). But what about OP? If I find question good enough to answer it, I think, OP should be awarded with vote-up.

However, I'd like to know other opinions -- whether this should be encouraged (in FAQ, in comments) or should remain as purely private opinion / decision?

Comment: Just another thing. As I just realized, we have a very low [number of users with high ranks](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63276/worldbuilding). We need it to progress to public beta and then to real-live site. I think voting as much as we can, not only on questions, but also on other's usable comments, is currently in our together interest.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the moment, in a small private beta with relatively low voting rates, your question makes sense. Even popular questions get few votes, so whether or not the answerer votes up makes a big difference. However, I see this as a short term phenomenon that won't be worth thinking about beyond private beta.

If a question is good enough that it is getting votes from viewers, then the answerer's vote will not make a significant difference. If a question is getting very few votes from viewers, then that suggests it is not a great question, and the answerer shouldn't feel obliged to upvote.

I think the answerer should choose whether to vote and whether to answer as two separate decisions. In most cases where I post an answer, it is because I found the question interesting, and so I upvote. I wouldn't want to be pressured to upvote though, or conversely pressured not to answer if I don't feel like upvoting.

There may be cases where a question is not off topic and there is no reason to close it, but it is not a particularly good question. Adding an answer that demonstrates the problems with the question and explains why there can be no definitive conclusions can be helpful for future reference, and if I saw such a situation I would upvote the answer but not the question.

Comment: Yes, this.  Most of the time, I suspect, people who answer the question also upvote it, but these are two separate decisions and we shouldn't push people to connect them.  It would be particularly sad if people *decline to answer* (i.e. decline to share their knowledge) because of a voting rule.

Comment: I have, on a few occasions, even posted answers to questions which I have *downvoted*. Let's not try to mandate any particular style of voting; it won't work anyway.

Comment: I must disagree. If you're voting up an answer to your own question, you see a nag reminder, that you should _consider_ accepting it. Even though, voting up and accepting answer are also two separate things. I see the same pattern in given scenario. Please, notice, that, I wrote "encourage", not "force". While most of your arguments are OK, I must admit, that it is very odd to me to see a zero-scored question with 3-5 answers. This looks for me a bit strange. But, since my vote is single, and most of you disagree with me, then let's end this discussion and leave the things as they're now.

Answer (score 10):

Bumping this one!  There are questions that get lots of answers but few upvotes: like this sweet one.  When I found it there were 7 answers and 0 votes.

[Is there a plausible way to build a pipette with medieval technology?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121646/is-there-a-plausible-way-to-build-a-pipette-with-medieval-technology)

If it is interesting enough for you to spend time answering I think that warrants an upvote.  Encourage people who post interesting questions!

Comment: Definitely! If we don't encourage people who ask interesting questions we will lose them. To the detriment to WB SE.